# Por que este algoritmo em Java não está executando?

Tags: java, algoritmo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculoSalarioLiquido {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        System.out.println("Programa para calcular o Salário Líquido: ");

        System.out.println("Escreva o Número de Horas Trabalhadas pelo Funcionário: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        double numerodehorastrabalhadas = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escreva o Número de Horas Extras Trabalhadas pelo Funcionário: ");
        double numerodehorasextras = sc.nextInt();

    **//Tem vários erros nestes quatro System.out.println. Estou com problemas na importação dos métodos, para depois imprimir os resultados. Erros de not a statement.** 
        System.out.println ("Salário Bruto: " (calcularsalariodofuncionario(numeroDeHorasTrabalhadas,numeroDeHorasExtras)));
        System.out.println ("Imposto de Renda: "calcularImpostodeRenda(salariobruto));
        System.out.println ("Seguro Social: " calcularSeguridadeSocial(salariobruto));
        System.out.println ("Salário Líquido: " calcularSalarioLiquido(salariobruto, seguridadesocial, impostoderenda));
    }

    public static double calcularsalariodofuncionario (double numeroDeHorasTrabalhadas, double numeroDeHorasExtras) {

        double salarioinicial = numerodehorastrabalhadas * 18.6;
        double salariosdashorasextras = 5.7 * numerodehorasextras;

        double salariobruto = salarioinicial + salariosdashorasextras;
        return salariobruto;
        }

    public static double calcularImpostoDeRenda(double salariobruto){
        double impostoderenda = salariobruto * 0.49;
        return impostoderenda;
    }

    public static double calcularSeguridadeSocial (double salariobruto){
        double seguridadesocial = salariobruto * 0.94;
        return seguridadesocial;
    }

    public static double calcularSalarioLiquido (double salariobruto, double seguridadesocial, double impostoderenda){
    double salarioliquido = salariobruto - seguridadesocial - impostoderenda;
    return salarioliquido;
    }
}
```

Como corrigir?

Comment: Pelo jeito faltou contenar a sida no `println()` use o `+` para isso. Ex `"ola "+ nome;`

Comment: @rray pior que é isso mesmo, erro de sintaxe entao.

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

O código está cheio de erros de digitação. Programar é detalhe. Precisa organizar o código, prestar atenção no que está digitando. Não é só largar um texto e pronto. Tem que prestar atenção, tomar cuidado, ser caprichoso. Tem que ler os erros, interpretá-los e corrigi-los.

Pode ficar bravo comigo, mas vou dizer uma coisa que é a mais importante nesse momento e o que mais vai te ajudar: tem que mudar a forma de programar, isso que está fazendo é só escrever códigos, não é criar programas. Essa forma não vai te levar a lugar algum.

Analise caractere por caractere que eu mudei. Sim, você vai perder meia hora fazendo isso, mas vai aprender alguma coisa. Se achar que é perda de tempo fazer isso continuará tendo dificuldades. A maioria é só problema de uso de maiúsculo e minúsculo, mas tem também a falta de concatenação do texto a ser impresso e tem a falta de armazenamento dos resultados das funções em variáveis locais.

Na verdade precisa adotar um padrão de nomes das variáveis. Procure usar [*camelCase*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) em todos os nomes de variáveis. Seja consistente! Eu não fiz porque é muita coisa errada, faça você como exercício. Não deixe de fazer! Pode parecer bobagem organizar assim, mas com o tempo perceberá que é muito importante para facilitar a leitura e achar os erros mais facilmente. Todos os programadores experientes organizam muito seu código. Comece fazer já.

Nem vou falar o uso errado do `double` para valores monetários, não está preparado para isto ainda.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CalculoSalarioLiquido {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        System.out.println("Programa para calcular o Salário Líquido: ");
        System.out.println("Escreva o Número de Horas Trabalhadas pelo Funcionário: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double numerodehorastrabalhadas = sc.nextInt(); // <===== nome ruim
        System.out.println("Escreva o Número de Horas Extras Trabalhadas pelo Funcionário: ");
        double numerodehorasextras = sc.nextInt();
        double salariobruto = calcularsalariodofuncionario(numerodehorastrabalhadas, numerodehorasextras);
        double impostoderenda = calcularImpostoDeRenda(salariobruto);
        double seguridadesocial = calcularSeguridadeSocial(salariobruto);
        System.out.println("Salário Bruto: " + salariobruto);
        System.out.println("Imposto de Renda: " + impostoderenda);
        System.out.println("Seguro Social: " + seguridadesocial);
        System.out.println("Salário Líquido: " + calcularSalarioLiquido(salariobruto, seguridadesocial, impostoderenda));
    }

    public static double calcularsalariodofuncionario(double numeroDeHorasTrabalhadas, double numeroDeHorasExtras) { // Nomes bons
        double salarioinicial = numeroDeHorasTrabalhadas * 18.6;
        double salariosdashorasextras = 5.7 * numeroDeHorasExtras;
        double salariobruto = salarioinicial + salariosdashorasextras;
        return salariobruto;
    }

    public static double calcularImpostoDeRenda(double salariobruto) {
        double impostoderenda = salariobruto * 0.49;
        return impostoderenda;
    }

    public static double calcularSeguridadeSocial(double salariobruto) {
        double seguridadesocial = salariobruto * 0.94;
        return seguridadesocial;
    }

    public static double calcularSalarioLiquido(double salariobruto, double seguridadesocial, double impostoderenda) {
        double salarioliquido = salariobruto - seguridadesocial - impostoderenda;
        return salarioliquido;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UeAUbj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bzpahscl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/SimulPayroll.java).

Comment: Pessoal, eu concatenei, mas mesmo assim não acha as variáveis.
Testem na IDE de vocês?
Não sei como corrigir.

Comment: @InicianteemJava não vai achar mesmo, tem que escrever certo as minusculas e maiusculas. Vc ta misturando tudo no seu código. Pra falar a verdade, você está tentando fazer coisa muito complicada pra quem ta iniciando, sugeriria começar pelo mais básico. Aprenda as coisas essenciais primeiro, senão vai ficar igual os eternos copiadores e coladores de código que não aprendem a programar.

Comment: Corrigi todas as maiúsculas e minúsculas, mas mesmo assim está dando erro nos 3 últimos System.out.println.
Não está achando as variáveis que já foram declaradas nos métodos.
Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Pra isso você tem que se ajudar primeiro. Que erro está dando? Grande chance de ter faltado corrigir algo ainda. Declarou as variáveis no escopo certo? Se tentar usar uma variável que é de outro método, não vai funcionar.

Comment: Os erros é que a IDE não consegue achar nos 3 últimos System.out.println do método main, as variáveis que já foram calculadas nos métodos posteriores.

Comment: Não funciona assim. Como disse no comentário anterior, as variáveis não saem do escopo em que foram declaradas. Em main não existe nenhuma das variáveis mesmo, o compilador não faz milagre. É tarefa do programador guardar o retorno das funções dentro das variáveis que vai usar.

Comment: Todos os erros são de sintaxe, você não está concatenando corretamente as strings dentro dos println. Recomendo a leitura sobre o tema para evitar esses problemas http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/string.php

Comment: @diegofm tem erro de escopo tambem, ele está tentando usar variáveis que não existem, só pq usou nomes similares em outras funções. Infelizmente ele começou com um código muito complicado pro nivel atual de conhecimento.

Comment: Na verdade tem erro que não é de sintaxe. @InicianteemJava aproveite todos os comentários e a minha nova resposta. Comece com coisas bem mais simples, ainda está errando em detalhes mais básicos. Pular um passo só vai atrapalhar. Eu entendo que queira ver coisas legais funcionando, mas é mais legal aprender um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Pessoal, eu quero aprender. Podem me falar  exatamente no que eu estou errando?

Comment: @InicianteemJava leia por completo a resposta do bigown, ela é bem esclarecedora. Em pequenos erros assim, as vezes é melhor quebrar a cabeça agora sozinho enquanto estar começando, do que depois em um grande projeto, ser culpado de algo que cause prejuizos pra uma grande empresa.

Comment: @InicianteemJava basta reler os comentários e o monte de correções que o bigown fez, tá praticamente tudo explicadinho. Sò que tem que ler com calma e entender. Não se preocupe, pq esquentar os miolos faz parte do aprendizado. Leia e releia quantas vezes for preciso, que isso vai ajudar não só no código, mas aumentar a facilidade de pensar. Aproveite o tempo que o bigown investiu na sua pergunta, e compare tudo que foi mudado, e tente entender as razões.

Comment: Muito obrigado, pessoal.

Answer (score 4):

Para você usar uma variável, ela tem que estar no escopo do método, neste caso, faltou a declaração da variável salariobruto. Java é uma linguagem que tem "Case sensitive", ou seja, tem diferença entre letras em caixa alta e baixa. Os parametros que está passando em System.out.println("Salário Bruto: "(calcularsalariodofuncionario(numeroDeHorasTrabalhadas,numeroDeHorasExtras))); está diferente da que foi declarada, e para mostrar String e valores na mesma linha tem que utilizar o sinal de + para concatenar os valores. Os nomes do seus metedos que está chamando no System.out.println, também está diferente do que foi declarado. Faça essas correções que irá funcionar.